# Spine003 keeps stretching book in undesirable way

Tags: vertices

I'm trying to fix this rig so that it all bends together, but for some reason the vertices selected below keep stretching in undesirable ways. I've tried a couple different things to no avail. Can anyone help?
[image]

If you grab the spine.003 and rotate it in any direction, you will see what I mean.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neePPk9PlKjhpp8AIbUOF94m1KHws7hX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at it in edit mode and show the item properties, you'll see that the vertices are linked to several groups and two of them corresponds to two bones.

[image]

Depending on what you want to do, you may remove the unwanted bones influences from all the vertices of the book.

If the book is not supposed to be bent maybe you should keep only one bone influence for it (all its vertices).

Comment: Thanks for that. But I've changed every vertice on the object to the same thing, spine.002@ 0.4 and spine.003@ 1.00, and it still bends in an uneven way.

Comment: @LuckyCOINNNN, you have to keep only **one** bone influence if you don't want the book to bend.